# Входные сигналы Verilog

Tags: verilog

Как написать код на Verilog, чтобы в ModelSim можно было получить данные три входных сигнала (второй сигнал есть, когда первый находится в состоянии 1, третий сигнал — когда первый равен 0)?

Вот что у меня получилось. В итоге сигналы получились одинаковыми:

```
module fvds;
    reg clk1;

    always begin
        clk1 = 1'b0;
        forever #20000000  clk1 = !clk1;
    end

    reg clk2;

    initial begin
        clk2 = 0;
        #20;
        clk2 = 1;
        #20;
    end
endmodule
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`timescale 1us/1us

module tb;
    reg clk = 1;
    always #4000 clk <= !clk; /* 250 Hz */

    reg sin = 0;
    always #20 sin <= !sin && clk; /* 50 kHz */

    reg cos = 0;
    always #20 cos <= !cos && !clk; /* 50 kHz */
endmodule
```

Симуляция выдает вот такую волну:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В общем да, но надо чтобы у первого сигнала частота была 250 Гц, у второго и третьего-50 кГц.

Comment: Вот что   я сделал, но сигнал sin не отслеживает измение clk,          module fvds;
    reg clk = 1;
    always #40000 clk <= !clk;

    reg clk2, sin;

initial begin clk2 = 1'b0;
forever #50  clk2 = !clk2;
end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
  
    Sin <=clk2;

  
end
endmodule

Comment: @zeratul314, я обновил ответ, взгляните.